# creating JSON payloads schemas to fit javascript D3

Tags: d3.js, neo4j, cypher

I have some neo4j graphs and I want to export their information in a JSON that’s compatible with javascript.D3.

I found a fairly reasonable tutorial of doing so at this link :
https://neo4j.com/developer/example-project/

However, the one thing I don’t understand is how the following data was generated

```
// JSON object for whole graph viz (nodes, links - arrays)
curl http://localhost:8080/graph[?limit=50]

{"nodes":
  [{"title":"Apollo 13","label":"movie"},{"title":"Kevin Bacon","label":"actor"},
   {"title":"Tom Hanks","label":"actor"},{"title":"Gary Sinise","label":"actor"},
   {"title":"Ed Harris","label":"actor"},{"title":"Bill Paxton","label":"actor"}],
 "links":
  [{"source":1,"target":0},{"source":2,"target":0},{"source":3,"target":0},
   {"source":4,"target":0},{"source":5,"target":0}]}
```

I don’t understand how the JSON payload above is generated.

All of my neo4j graphs are exported in a neo4j JSON (which is a more complex payload structure than the one above). Which is alright but I specifically want to generate the code shown above. A curl command is just going to fetch existing data, so at the very least I need existing data formatted properly which I don’t have.

Comment: It's done in code.

Comment: does neo4j share that code anywhere ?